# Set Configuration value in Spark-SQL Shell

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can I set a configuration parameter value in the spark SQL Shell ?

In spark-shell can use :

```
scala> spark.config.set("spark.sql.optimizer.excludeRules", "org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.PushDownPredicate");
```

But, I wish to know how to do the same by using the `SET` command in the **spark-sql shell**. I have tried using the `SET` command in Spark-**Sql** shell, but it doesn't seem to be working. Is this the correct way ?

Something like:

```
spark-sql> SET spark.sql.optimizer.excludeRules org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.PushDownPredicate;
```

How can I use the `SET` command ? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just needed to put an "=" in your query. Thanks (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desired result could be achieved by the following from the `spark-sql`:

```
SET spark.sql.optimizer.excludedRules=org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.PushDownPredicate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.multiobjectdelete.enable", "false")
```

or

```
spark.sql("SET spark.sql.hive.metastore.version=2.3.2"). 

// spark: SparkSession
```

Comment: thanks, but this does not help me. I want to use `SET`in the Spark **SQL** API to set the following value: `SET "spark.sql.optimizer.excludeRules " "org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.PushDownPredicate";`

Comment: spark.sql("SET spark.sql.hive.metastore.version=2.3.2") . spark is SparkSession

Comment: so for setting my desired configuration i should use the following - `spark.sql("SET spark.sql.optimizer.excludeRules  = org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.PushDownPredicate")` ?

Comment: that did not work.. To give you some context - I read about setting th the following  configuration values like this - `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.optimizer.excludeRules", "org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.PushDownPredicate");` in the spark shell using DataFrame API.. Now my question is -  how I can set those same configurations  using`SET` command in the `Spark-SQL` shell using the **SQL API**?